# filtering by domain

Tags: networking, filter, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I want to filter my pcap file by their domains. I mean, I want to see the packets comes on a website ends with ".com", ".org" or ".net".

I tried:
dns contains "com", 
ip.src_host == com, 
ip.src_host == com, 
http contains "com". None of them worked correctly.

Comment: Are these saved capture files your are trying to filter or running capture files? from http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvNameResolutionSection.html The resolved names are not stored in the capture file or somewhere else. Resolved DNS names are cached by Wireshark.

Comment: They are already captured files. Thank you for ur answer Thaddeus.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming it's http web traffic, try `http.host contains ".com"`

Better yet, try `http.host matches "\.com$"`

Neither one will require DNS resolution since they search on the web host.

From http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters

```
The matches operator makes it possible to search for text in string fields 
and byte sequences using a regular expression, using Perl regular expression 
syntax. Note: Wireshark needs to be built with libpcre in order to be able to 
use the matches operator.
```

Comment: May I ask, when I write "http" as filter, I cant see any packet. However, when I write "tcp.port == 80", i can see many packet. Do u think why it happens like that?